# how to send user it with access jwt token in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

Currently I'm using `JWT` token in django rest framework, while using `login` api, i just get `refresh token` & `access token`. I'm wondring if could send the user id with these tokens too(i have no idea on if it's possible or not)

currently

```
{
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYyMjk3NzY2OCwianRpIjoiYWE2ZTk0NWNiYjRjNDAxZmFiMmM2NWEzZWQ1Yzg5NDUiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.a54fcfa0ZsFrfVrb1VTdRO6bXY47NOuZqO8T1I3yKCc",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjU0NDI3MjY4LCJqdGkiOiI1ODEwNDQyZWU3ZTM0MzczYTBkNmEzMDBkYmRmYTg2MyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.d6fmMq6ddsCaCyAEbDDaE5aja04LxYZmRP8WHfpmJqs"
}
```

what i want

```
{
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYyMjk3NzY2OCwianRpIjoiYWE2ZTk0NWNiYjRjNDAxZmFiMmM2NWEzZWQ1Yzg5NDUiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.a54fcfa0ZsFrfVrb1VTdRO6bXY47NOuZqO8T1I3yKCc",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjU0NDI3MjY4LCJqdGkiOiI1ODEwNDQyZWU3ZTM0MzczYTBkNmEzMDBkYmRmYTg2MyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.d6fmMq6ddsCaCyAEbDDaE5aja04LxYZmRP8WHfpmJqs",
    "userid": <id>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you using django-rest-framework-simplejwt, this can helpful. write your custom login function and add it in url path.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        'user': user
    }

# in views.py
def login(request):
    ...
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        user_id = User.objects.get(email=email)
        data = get_tokens_for_user(user_id)
        return Response(data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```